# How can I print a referenced media extension

Tags: theming

I am working in the node template. In my content type I have a referenced field to media called 'field_event'. I created a new media type called 'document'. Inside document there is a file upload field called 'field_document'.
I need to print the file name, size and extension all separately in table cells. 
Example: Myfile | 80kb | pdf

This renders the file, link and name.

```
{{ content.field_event }}
```

Gives me: mypdf.pdf 80.00 KB, This is the name of my pdf

This prints out only the name

```
{{ node.field_event.entity.name.value }}
```

Gives me: This is the name of my pdf

How can I get the file extension? I have tried these.

```
{{ node.field_event.document.entity.field_document.entity.filesize.value }}

{{ node.field_event|field_target_entity.field_mime_type.value }}

{{ node.field_event|field_target_entity.field_mime_type.entity.filemime.value }}
```

I am using [twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

Answer (score 1):

```
{% set extension = node.field_event.entity.filemime.value|split('/') %}
{% set extensionDot = '.' ~ extension[1] %}


// File name
{{ node.field_event.entity.filename.value|replace({extensionDot : ''}) }}

// File size
{{ node.field_event.entity.filesize.value / 1000|round }}KB

// File extension
{{ extension[1] }}
```